# IS there a way to do zk proof on string?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

For example: "I am a very secret person".

I'd like to show someone that this string includes 'secret' without revealing the rest of the string. Is there anyway?

Comment: https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2010/6477196/6477196.pdf